# Jupyter notebook slowing (to the point cannot load) down since the script is too long

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My script seems to generate a lot of outputs. The next time I try to go in my ipynb file it is impossible to load.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If you're printing output then you can store that in an external file OR before saving .ipynb file clear the output from the toolbar (Cell -> All Output -> Clear)